# Overriding js file not working in Magento 2.

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I am trying to override

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/MyTheme/Package/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js
```

in order to change the "Add to Cart" button text. I modified the only instance of "Add to Cart" in the js file.

```
 setTimeout(function () {
            var addToCartButtonTextDefault = self.options.addToCartButtonTextDefault || $t('Add to Basket');
```

I fired cache:clean, cache:flush, setup:upgrade, but the text is still not changing. What step am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 places where you need to change the text and then it will show your changes these are ( `if these files are not in your theme then place these files in your theme folder , where i assume **/Vendor/theme** is your theme folders` ):

1 - **/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml**
in this file you should change

```
<?php **$buttonTitle = __('Add to Basket');** ?>
```

this will change button title but only when it will load the page , but when you will hit that button it will change back to **"Add to cart"**. So you need to make change in js file ( which you have mentioned in your question already )

2 - **/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js**

```
var addToCartButtonTextDefault = self.options.addToCartButtonTextDefault || $t('Add to Basket');
```

If you are already in developer mode then :

After making these changes you just need to run cache:clean command if that still not work then deploy:static:content.

Answer (score 3):

you just need to add your text into language csv file, no need to override any js file

> app/design/frontend/Customtheme/default/i18n/en_US.csv

add like **"Add to Cart","Add to Basket"**

run below command

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

check your changes.

Answer (score 1):

To change  the text of "Add to Cart" button, you need to do changes in its view template file.

-- Enable template path hint from admin and find the path of template file of that button.

-- Override that template view file in your theme folder and then do required changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your rrequirement is to change text of "Add To Cart" button then you need to do using custom extension by overiding this.

1. You need to overide `"addtocart.phtml"` file.

   ```
   app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml
   ```

   ```
   <body>
       <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
           <action method="setTemplate">
               <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Extension::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
           </action>
       </referenceBlock>
   </body>
   ```

   2. create template file "addtocart.phtml" file at this location.

      ```
      app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\templates\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml
      ```

Into this file, copy orignal file code, just replace this line.

```
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
```

to

```
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Basket'); ?>
```